# error de sintaxis php en heredoc

Tags: php, sintaxis

estoy trasteando con php y nose porque me da un error de sintaxis dentro de un heredoc

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in /midirectorio/test.php on line 273

la línea 273 es:

```
data: [$datos_horas_pm['24-2v2'], $datos_horas_pm['23-2v2'], $datos_horas_pm['22-2v2'], $datos_horas_pm['21-2v2'], $datos_horas_pm['20-2v2'], $datos_horas_pm['19-2v2'], $datos_horas_pm['18-2v2'], $datos_horas_pm['17-2v2'], $datos_horas_pm['16-2v2'], $datos_horas_pm['15-2v2'], $datos_horas_pm['14-2v2'], $datos_horas_pm['13-2v2'], $datos_horas_am['12-2v2'], $datos_horas_am['11-2v2'], $datos_horas_am['10-2v2'], $datos_horas_am['9-2v2'], $datos_horas_am['8-2v2'], $datos_horas_am['7-2v2'], $datos_horas_am['6-2v2'], $datos_horas_am['5-2v2'], $datos_horas_am['4-2v2'], $datos_horas_am['3-2v2'], $datos_horas_am['2-2v2'], $datos_horas_am['1-2v2']],
```

abro el heredoc con:

```
echo <<<EOT
```

y lo cierro con

```
EOT;
```

sin espacios ni tabulaciones al final.

Saludos y gracias.

Comment: la idea es que PHP interprete el valor de esas variables dentro del heredoc, o no??

Answer (score 0):

Al principio de la línea lo que dice **data** qué es ? es una variable ? no le veo el signo **$** y si es una variable después va un signo de **=** y tampoco veo al final de esa línea el cierre **;**

deberia ser algo como esto: **$data** **=** [$datos_horas_pm['24-2v2'], $datos_horas_pm['23-2v2'], ... ]**;**

saludos.

Comment: estoy imprimiendo HTML y JavaScript con un heredoc de PHP, la variable data es de javascript

Comment: y bueno sobre el **heredoc** debes  poner este tipo de variables así: {$datos_horas_pm['24-2v2']}  usando **{}**

Comment: Eso si funciono :) muchas gracias amigo

Comment: Está explicado en [Análisis de variables](http://php.net/manual/es/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing) .. quizás convenga que agregues algo de eso en tu respuesta

Comment: por cierto vaya castaña el heredoc de php si funciona asi, el de Perl es superior

Comment: @Akond interpola las variables en un heredoc de la misma forma que se interpolan en comillas dobles... Es la sintaxis, no significa que sea superior... Pero viendo al contenido de tu heredoc, pareciera más sencillo que lo ordenes y uses un join, en vez de estar escribiendo c/u en el heredoc.